# APNS Hosting Providers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification

I'm thinking of adding push notifications to my app however it looks quite expensive and complex (VPS servers etc).

I'm just wondering if there's anyone who knows of hosting providers who specifically help with setting up APNs and offer dedicated packages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to have a complex or expensive hosting service and all.

You only need a simple web hosting service (like any host you would subscribe to host a web site, you may even already have one if you have a website), and then use a framework like [easyapns](http://www.easyapns.com/) on the server to ease the managment of your push notifications.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I saw easyapns however this requires me to upgrade to a virtual private server or similar which costs a lot.  Something like Urban  Airship that was suggested would bring the cost way down if I'm not mistaken.  Or is this somehow not the case?

Comment: unless your hosting provider permits outgoing connections to port 2195, which is used to send notifications to the APNs

Answer (score 3):

How about [urban airship](http://urbanairship.com)?

$0.001 per message, 
1st million free per month

Comment: Not free anymore. http://urbanairship.com/blog/2014/06/26/changes-coming-to-urban-airships-free-developer-edition

Answer (score 0):

With shared hosting you'll most probably have blocked ports making communications with Apns servers impossible.  The problem with saas providers(urban airship et al) is that it isn't customisable to your needs. Put it this way: does fb, twitter etc use a third party for their push services? It depends on your needs as to what you need for hosting.